# jQuery go to the next section on every click

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, smooth-scrolling

What I am trying to achieve is one single button in a position fixed which on every click it will take me to the next section on the page
(A section with a class "next-section" in my case)

I started with this code:

```
var $a = $('.down-btn'), $targets = $('div.next-section').next();
$a.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log($targets);
    var i = $a.index(this);
    var offset = $targets.eq(++i).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 400);
});
```

But this only works with one click - one time
I need it to take me to the next section in every click on the button
Would appreciate an answer
Thanks

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/hamergil/jv3ja3wp/12/

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with your HTML code also?

Comment: Added to the original post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the code like below

1.Use  `counter` variable and increased it inside click handler before scroll code.

2.Use `.next()` inside `click` handler to get correct element position for scroll.

```
var i = 0;
$('.down-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  i++;
  var offset = $("div.next-section").eq(i).offset().top;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 400);
});
```

Working snippet:- https://jsfiddle.net/uj91djeL/1/

Comment: Yes. @Alive to Die It is now working if you add more sections.. for example try to add another green section and the button will work only for the red section 
See updated fiddle with your code and more sections
https://jsfiddle.net/hamergil/jv3ja3wp/38/

Comment: @gilhamer  check my edited solution and working link now

Comment: Looks great @Alive to Die
Just what if I scroll back up. it won't work? I have to refresh the page?
is it possible to make it work when scrolling back up?

Comment: @gilhamer  Asking new questions in the comment is not right. You need to ask a new question for your new requirement.You can address me the link. If I will be free then I will answer it. Otherwise, you will get an answer from someone for sure.Thanks